# How can I update a NuGet package on Visual Studio Team Services after NuGet Publish?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package, azure-pipelines

I'm looking to chain together multiple CI builds on VSTS. The flow would be that once code is checked in on a project destined to be a NuGet Package, that it will be built, and published to our Internal NuGet Feed as a prerelease package.

This works fine, but what I'm having a problem with is when I kick off the next CI build, which is for a project that depends on the NuGet package I just published, I don't know how I can upgrade that one specific package to the latest prerelease version that was just published.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to this steps to update NuGet package during the build.

1. Include Nuget.exe to your project and check in to source control (you can add Nuget.exe to other folder in source control and map it to the agent during the build)
2. Add Command Line build step (**Tool:** $(build.sourcesdirectory)\FeedRestoreDemo\Tool\nuget.exe; **Arguments:** sources add -name vstsTestfeed -source [your feed url] -username [user name] -password [password] -StorePasswordInClearText
3. Add Nuget Installer (Restore) build step to restore packages
4. Add Command Line build step (**Tool:** $(build.sourcesdirectory)\FeedRestoreDemo\Tool\nuget.exe; **Arguments:** update FeedRestoreDemo.sln; Working folder: $(build.sourcesdirectory) (my solution path is  $(build.sourcesdirectory)\ FeedRestoreDemo.sln)

There are many options of [nuget update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/nuget-exe-cli-reference#update) command, such as id (Specifies a list of package IDs to update.), you can modify the command per to your requirements.